# Ошибка при входе под незарегистрированным пользователем

Tags: php, html

Если зайти как незарегистрированный пользователь, то выходят такие надписи. А если захожу под логином, то надпись исчезает.

> Warning: include(/var/www/zvasy141/data/www/fotozov.ru/templates/Photoshop/images/fon.jpg): failed to open stream: оЕФ ФБЛПЗП ЖБКМБ ЙМЙ ЛБФБМПЗБ in /var/www/zvasy141/data/www/fotozov.ru/templates/Photoshop/login.tpl on line 38   Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/zvasy141/data/www/fotozov.ru/templates/Photoshop/images/fon.jpg' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/zvasy141/data/www/fotozov.ru/templates/Photoshop/login.tpl on line 38

Как я понимаю, проблема с fon.jpg, но я его не могу открыть, там попросту нет никакого изображения (при просмотре чёрный экран). Посмотрел его в шаблоне у себя на компе и там то же самое, сам файл есть, а просмотреть его невозможно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Вот сам файл login.tpl

```
<?php
if ($is_logged == TRUE) {

    $login_panel = <<<HTML
    <div style="padding-top:2px; padding-left:20px;">Привет, <b>{$member_id['name']}</b>!</div>
    <div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:22px;">
        <table width="100%" class="copy">
            HTML;

            if ($user_group[$member_id['user_group']]['allow_admin']) {
                $login_panel .= <<<HTML
                <tr>
                <td><a href="{$adminlink}" target="_blank">Админцентр</a></td>
                </tr>
                HTML;
            }
            $login_panel .= <<<HTML
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{$link_profile}">Мой профиль</a></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><a href="{$link_pm}">Cообщения ({$member_id['pm_unread']} | {$member_id['pm_all']})</a></td>
                <tr>
                <td><a href="{$link_favorites}">Мои закладки</a></td>

                <tr>
                <td><a href="{$link_stats}">Статистика</a></td>
                <tr>
                <td><a href="{$link_addnews}">Добавить новость</a></td>
                <tr>
                <td><a href="{$link_newposts}">Обзор непрочитанного</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:75px;"><a onclick="javascript: showBusyLayer()" href="{$link_logout}"><b>Выход</b></a></div>
    HTML;

} else {

    $void = include ($tpl->dir.'/images/fon.jpg');
    $get_good = $void;

    if (isset($get_good) == true)
    { 
        $login_panel = $void;
        $login_panel .= <<<HTML

        <form class="LoginForm" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:showBusyLayer()">
            &nbsp;<a href="{$link_regist}">Регистрация</a> / <a href="{$link_lost}">Забыли пароль?</a><br /><br />
            <div class="Input"><input name="login_name" class="Input2" type="text" value="Логин" onfocus="if (this.value=='Логин') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Логин';"/></div>
            <div class="Input"><input class="Input2" name="login_password" type="text"  value="Пароль"" onfocus="if (this.value=='Пароль') { this.value=''; this.type='password';}" onblur="if (this.value=='') { this.value='Пароль'; this.type='text';}"/></div>
            <div class="Panel">
                <input type="submit" name="submit_enter" value="Вход" class="LoginButton"/>
                <input name="login" type="hidden" id="login" value="submit">
            </div>
        </form>

        HTML;
    } else { 
        exit;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Ннадо было просто добавить пустой файл картинки и всё.

Comment: @z_vasya Обратите внимание на наши исправления: это поможет вам повысить качество задаваемых вопросов. А чем выше качество вопроса, тем выше качество ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Непонятно зачем использовать include для включения картинки в страницу.

```
$void = include ($tpl->dir.'/images/fon.jpg');
$get_good = $void;
```

В этом случае интерпретатор просто пытается вставить содержимое файла fon.jpg в скрипт и интерпретировать его как кусок программы на php. Естественно это ему не удается и пхп выдает ошибку.
Если вы хотели сделать ее фоном, то стоило бы воспользоваться тегами типа

```
echo "<body background=\"{$tpl->dir}/images/fon.jpg\">";
```